# Merge objects based on preference into one

Tags: javascript

I need to merge all the 5 objects with preference over 'X' and 'AND' into one.

Dynamically any object can be empty.

**Input**

```
   const cpc = {"L1":"NA","L2":"X","L3":"NA","L4":"NA","L3L4":"AND"}
   const ph  = {} 
   const pt  = {"L1":"NA","L2":"NA","L3":"X","L4":"NA","L3L4":"AND"}
   const cr  = {"L1":"X","L2":"NA","L3":"NA","L4":"NA","L3L4":"NA"}
   const mi  = {}
```

**Output:**

```
const or = {"L1":"X","L2":"X","L3":"X","L4":"NA","L3L4":"AND"}
```

**Code**

I am trying merge 1&2 ,3&4 and merge output of 1,2 with 5 but not sure if there is a better way

```
   cr= Object.assign(...Object.keys(cpc).map(key => ({[key]: cpc[key] === "NA" ? ph[key] : cpc[key] })));
```

Bu I am getting error as TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object if the object is empty

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that [flattens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the input arrays, and reduces to a result object:

```js
const cpc = {"L1":"NA","L2":"X","L3":"NA","L4":"NA","L3L4":"AND"};
const ph  = {};
const pt  = {"L1":"NA","L2":"NA","L3":"X","L4":"NA","L3L4":"AND"};
const cr  = {"L1":"X","L2":"NA","L3":"NA","L4":"NA","L3L4":"NA"};
const mi  = {};

const result =  [cpc, ph, pt, cr, mi]
                   .map(Object.entries)
                   .flat().reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({
                       ...a,
                       [k]: !a[k] || a[k] === 'NA' ? v : a[k]
                   }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Robby. Since I am using node version < 11 flat is not working.

Comment: The linked MDN page presents alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach:** Create an array out of all the objects and loop through each object storing the results in temp object. Check if temp object already contains the "X" and "AND" as values to key otherwise create new key value pair

```js
const cpc = {"L1":"NA","L2":"X","L3":"NA","L4":"NA","L3L4":"AND"}
const ph  = {} 
const pt  = {"L1":"NA","L2":"NA","L3":"X","L4":"NA","L3L4":"AND"}
const cr  = {"L1":"X","L2":"NA","L3":"NA","L4":"NA","L3L4":"NA"}
const mi  = {}

const objs = [cpc, ph, pt, cr, mi]
const tempObj = {}
objs.forEach((obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (!(tempObj[key] == "X" || tempObj[key] == "AND")) {
      tempObj[key] = obj[key]
    }
  })
})

console.log(tempObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array with objects and check the value in advance.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => Object.entries(b).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
        if (!['X', 'AND'].includes(o[k])) o[k] = v;
        return o;
    }, a),
    cpc = { L1: "NA", L2: "X", L3: "NA", L4: "NA", L3L4: "AND" },
    ph = {},
    pt = { L1: "NA", L2: "NA", L3: "X", L4: "NA", L3L4: "AND" },
    cr = { L1: "X", L2: "NA", L3: "NA", L4: "NA", L3L4: "NA" },
    mi = {},
    merged = [cpc, ph, pt, cr, mi].reduce(merge, {});

console.log(merged);
```